# C++ error: Reference to non-static member function must be called, Please help, don't know whats literally wrong

Tags: c++, syntax-error

```
class skClass {
    public:
    void setName(string x) {
        name = x;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private:
    string name;
};

int main() {

    skClass sk;
    sk.setName = ("Mr Bashir Sentongo");
    cout << sk.getName() << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: error on the setter : sk.setName ("Mr Bashir Sentongo");

Answer (score 2):

Methods are called by passing parameters within parenthesis (`()`), not with the assignment operator (`=`):

I.e., you should replace

```
sk.setName = ("Mr Bashir Sentongo");
```

With

```
sk.setName("Mr Bashir Sentongo");
```

Comment: Cheers, I'm just silly, just put the = by mistake, thanks its working now.